# Connecting to Podio API from VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, podio

I have created a console application using VB.NET which stores data in SQL. I now want to ship data logged in SQL into Podio as currently I use the Podio import feature.

I'm experienced with VB.NET however my web development experience is limited. Can someone please give me some pointers as to what is required to get a desktop application to connect to Podio?

For example I am unsure what to specify as the **Full Domain** when generating the API Key. Do I need to use IIS in some way?

I am already connecting to an API (https://www.planit.org.uk/api/) in another application using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq however this API does not require authentication. Can I do something similar with Podio or is a different approach needed? For that I had to deal with JSON, however I see on the Podio API documentation that there is an API wrapper, could that make things easier?

Regards,

Carl

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this by using the following: http://podio.github.io/podio-dotnet/